# Rails, managing access of dashboard pages by models roles. Using devise

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, model-view-controller, devise, routes

I am creating dashboard appliaction on Rails4. I have created model `Partner` with some data. I also have created a lot of models with views that will be associated to this `Partner`.

I can edit data of all models without any restrictions. Now I want to create `Admin`, that will login to my app and will manage data. `Admins` will be added via console and it does not need registration.

Also I want to make `Partners` to login/register too. `Partners` can only open pages that are connected to their data and edit them.

Here my questions depending on this situation:

1. How to remove registration element from `Admins` not affecting to `Partners`?
2. How to restrict `Partners` to only their own pages while `Admins` can be everywhere?
3. Is it good approach to make `Admins` and `Partners` to edit data on same dashboard, or I need to create different controllers with different views for `Admins` and `Partners` separately?

Comment: For ACL use cancancan https://github.com/CanCanCommunity/cancancan

Comment: According to your link, https://github.com/ryanb/cancan is considered dead?

Comment: According to my link cancancan is not. This is the continuator of cancan

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to do everything you're discussing by using a gem for handling authorization ( authority ) and one for roles ( rolify )

https://github.com/nathanl/authority

https://github.com/RolifyCommunity/rolify

You shouldn't have to create distinct views/controllers, however, depending on how divergent they are it may be appropriate.  You should be able to do most of that logic by using logic to switch based on the permissions you set up.

```
current_user.can_edit?(page)
```

within the Authorization setup, you would have to determine who can edit/view/create/etc.  There's a good writeup for doing this in the authority wiki.